# Best way to name derived classes when extending its functionality

Tags: c#, object-oriented, naming, solid, naming-standards

I have just recently joined a new company and one of the classes used to log information has not been written properly. So I have been asked to add new functionality to the logger.

Rather than amending the `Logger` class I want to follow the O in SOLID and extend the class by creating a derived class and adding functionality that way. My issue however is, what do I name this derived logger class?
`NewLogger` or `LoggerTwo` just seem like poor class names.

The functionality I am trying to extend is adding statuses to the log. So I could call it `StatusLogger`. But that doesn’t seem right either because the logger does more than log statuses. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "add statuses"? Is there an extra parameter "status" passed at each "log" call? Would someone may come up with the requirement to activate or deactivate status logging at run time? Or is the idea to have two "log" members, one just with a text as parameter, and a second with text + status field? And what exactly are the specific use cases? Good naming is hard and requires context, and this question hardly provide enough context to let strangers like us make a good recommendation.

Comment: ... also, did you derive from the existing logger because you were not allowed to change the original loggers code? Or are you allowed, but just hesitating since you are "the new member" in the team?

Comment: The logger has a constructor that takes in the arguments to be logged. I want to add an additonal argument to allow the statuses to be logged. What status is doesnt really matter. Its just an additional parameter to be logged

Comment: If there are no technical or organizational reasons which forbid to change the original logger code (in a backwards-compatible fashion, and with a low risk of breaking existing code, of course), then I am with Philip - it is probably best to keep the old logger and extend it's code. The fact you have problems with coming up with a new name is a clear sign you actually don't want a new logger abstraction, you want the old one extended, If there are, however, hard reasons which forbid to change the old code, use some arbitrary name like "ExtendedLogger" ...

Comment: ... or a name which indicates the specific context in which this new logger will be used (assumed their will be a specific context where only this new logger will be required). For example, if the new logger is part of `ModuleFoo` and only used there, you could name it `FooLogger`. That's why I am stressing the context here. Unfortunately, it seems you were too lazy to give more information, so I am voting to close ("needs details or clarity").

Comment: Thanks Doc Brown. TBH I actually didnt tell the full story. They have actually called the logger DBLogger. That name is one reason to change it. The next reason is the DBLogger also manages the state aswell as logs. So theres another reason to change it. TBH the most senior guy in the company is so scared of change. But I will change it anyway. Explain why the old way was a code smell and if he still moans I will go with the Extended Logger name. Thank you

Comment: There is absolutely zero point in creating a subclass, if the class and its complete source code are available to you. So you just change the name, and do whatever other changes you need to make. I find people talking about "code smells" extremely insulting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds very much like you should just be fixing the bug in the original class, not creating a new one. Open-closed does *not* mean that you never fix bugs in the original class, it just means that it is possible to change it's behaviour without modifying it.

In this particular case, would anyone ever use the unmodified version of the class? If not, then there is no value in it without modifying, and no value in creating a new class.

Comment: This answer is fine, but let me stress that I would have written "Open-closed does not mean that you never *change anything* in the original class" (not just fixing bugs, that is what several people misunderstand). The OCP is about the design of the original logger, for *making it possible* to add new features / extensions.